# AutoMapping List with Default Values

Tags: c#, automapper

My problem can be reduced to basically the following set of entities :

I have an entity say : `MyEntity` which has a list of `EntityTiming` (named Timings)

```
public class Entity{

  public List<EntityTiming> Timings {get;set;}

}
```

It corresponds to a *ViewModel* : `MyEntityViewModel` which has a list of `TimingViewModel` (named Timings).

```
public class EntityViewModel
{
   public IList<TimingViewModel> Timings {get;set;}
}
```

I have the following rules configured for mapping the direction : `entity -> viewModel`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity,EntityViewModel>

Mapper.CreateMap<EntityTiming,TimingViewModel>
```

The EntityViewModel.Timings **MUST** have 7 items. However the Enitity.Timings might have **less than 7 items / never more**.

My Question is : is there a way to provide default values if the item is null in the listing using `AutoMapper`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `AfterMap()`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityViewModel>()
      .AfterMap((src, dest) => { 
          if (dest.Timings == null) {
              // Populate default values
          }
          else if (dest.Timings.Count < 7) {
              // Populate the rest of the values
          }
       });
```